# Is it possible to use a list as "fields" for hasMany relation?

Tags: graphql, amazon-dynamodb

I have this types

```
type Utilisateur @model @auth(rules: [
    {allow: public},
    {allow: owner}
]) {
    id: ID!
    cognitoID: ID @index(name: "byCognitoID")
}
```

```
type Offre @model @auth(rules: [
    { allow: groups, groups: ["Admin"] },
    { allow: owner, ownerField: "utilisateurID" },
    { allow: owner, ownerField: "guests", operations: [read] }
]) {
    guests: [ID]
    guestsProfile: [Utilisateur] @hasMany(indexName: "byCognitoID", fields: ["guests"])
    utilisateurID: ID!
}
```

I want to get Utilisateurs content, with the guests list when I query one Offre.
Is it possible ?

With this types I get this error:

> One or more parameter values were invalid: Condition parameter type
> does not match schema type